# Does NPM support encryption of the _auth property in .npmrc?

Tags: authentication, encryption, configuration, npm

By using `npm adduser`, my credentials get stored as a base64-encoded String `username:password` into the `~/.npmrc` file:

```
_auth=aGV5OmN1cmlvdXM7LSk=
```

Anyone with access to this file could easily decode this and find out my password.

Is it possible in NPM to encrypt the `_auth` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that they try to tackle this by using environment variables that are injected in .npmrc when needed:

> All npm config files are an ini-formatted list of key = value parameters. Environment variables can be replaced using ${VARIABLE_NAME}

from: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc

So, in your case you can save your password token in an env variable 
`export ENV_TOKEN=${mytoken}` and have your .npmrc file auth line changed to:
`_auth=${ENV_TOKEN}`

Comment: Using environment variable shouldn't be an option because the password is still plain in the environment variable.